# Wörtliches Zitieren und Quellenangabe nach Anführungsstrichen

Tags: punctuation

Ich möchte folgenden Satz numerisch ([9]) zitieren:

> Das Zeitalter der erneuerbaren Energien so schnell wie möglich erreichen und gleichzeitig den Preis für Strom bezahlbar halten.

Wie mache ich das jetzt richtig, da mein Zitat mit einem Satzende und Zitatverweis endet?

> "Das Zeitalter ... halten." [9]
>
> "Das Zeitalter ... halten" [9].

Wo muss das Satzzeichen hin?
Jeweils vor der eckigen Klammer steht ein Leerzeichen.
Im Duden habe ich direkt nichts gefunden, vielleicht übersehe ich aber etwas.

Sagt mir bitte auch, falls noch etwas anderes geändert werden sollte.

Comment: Sagt DIN ISO 690 etwas dazu oder die alte DIN 1505? Ich tendiere zu außerhalb, weil der Punkt zum zitierten Satz gehört und kein anderer, äußerer Satz vorliegt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich glaube, die Frage ist ein Zwischending zwischen Zeichensetzung und Typografie - Ich kenne auch keine Regel speziell für deinen Fall.

Für mich würde ich sie so beantworten, als ob die "[9]" ein hochgesetzter Fußnotenverweis wäre, und damit gehört für mich der Punkt *davor*. (Die Nummer bezieht sich ja normalerweise auf das ganze Zitat)

*Dazu* sagt der Duden nämlich was:

> Treffen Fußnoten mit Satzzeichen zusammen, gilt folgende Grundregel:
>
> Wenn sich die Fußnote auf den ganzen Satz bezieht, steht die Ziffer nach dem schließenden Satzzeichen; wenn die Fußnote sich nur auf das unmittelbar vorangehende Wort oder die unmittelbar vorangehende Wortgruppe bezieht, steht die Ziffer vor dem schließenden Satzzeichen.

Und die [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu%C3%9Fnote#Wissenschaftliche_Zeitschriften) sagt dazu das genaue Gegenteil, weiß aber dafür was von eckigen Klammern:

> Wissenschaftliche Zeitschriften
>
> Renommierte Wissenschaftsverlage wie Springer und Thieme platzieren in ihren Zeitschriften die Quellenangaben nicht als Fußnoten, sondern ans Artikelende. Die Verweise darauf setzen sie in eckigen Klammern auf die Grundlinie und beim Zusammentreffen mit einem Satzzeichen immer vor diesem.

Es wäre interessant zu wissen, ob diese zweite Aussage auf irgendwelche allgemeingültige Regeln zurückgeführt werden kann.

Comment: Ok, dein zweiter Absatz hilft mir, da ich nicht in der Fußnote zitieren möchte. Danke!